SSH Key only authentication not working for all users
am new to linux and I have a problem rn.
I built a RPI server with ubuntu server lts 24 os.
I am trying to protect my server with ssh key only authentication.
I made a keypair from my laptop (ubuntu 24 os) and shared the public key with my server and set the sshd_conf file like this.
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

it seems it is working for my laptop cause it doesn't request password
So I tried to access from my PC (ubuntu 24 os) which doesn't have the private key of my laptop to check that the server is not allowing to access with password.
But it is allowing my PC to access my server requesting the password.
I tried to access again from my PC to my server root through ssh and it didn't allowed me.
So I understood that ssh key  authentication only, is working only for my root but not for other users.
Why is that?
I appreciate all the help you can provide me!

Did you restart the ssh service after modifying the config? BTW you can't infer anything from your root test - that has its own default rule (PermitRootLogin prohibit-password)

Yes I restarted it, I reboot the server too, #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password, that commented out isn't it?, idk what's happening, please help!

sudo sshd -T | grep -i root
permitrootlogin without-password
chrootdirectory none

This question is similar to: Chages to sshd_config not disable password only login. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Assuming you have the regular sshd server installation on Ubuntu,
The ssh authorization happens only for the user you shared your public key with.
You can find the public key in:
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys for root
/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys for other users
There is several ways you can authorize the same public key for a new user.
1- Enable PasswordAuthentication temporarily
You can temporarily change to PasswordAuthentication yes in sshd_conf file.
ssh-copy-id <your-new-user>@<your-server-ip>

You will be prompted for password. After the process is done, you can disable PasswordAuthentication no back
2- Since you have access to shell of your server. You can manually add your public key
In your laptop

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
copy the public key to clipboard

after connection to your server as root, run these in your server
change <username> with any other user created on your server
# su <username>

$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.ssh/
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

open the authorized_keys file in nano editor
$ nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Paste the public-key from clipboard by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+V
Then press CTRL+X
Then press Y
Then press ENTER

Also, the sshd server configuration includes files in:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

I would recommend you to check if there is any file in there.

Thank you for taking the time:
Basically there was another config file overriding sshd_config.
this Config file was in my server in this location:
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/
the file name was this:
50-cloud-init.conf
When I edited this file I found the only line in this file was
PasswordAuthentication Yes
So I just did:
cd /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/
sudo nano 50-cloud-init.conf
PasswordAuthentication No

exit and save the file and now it will not override sshd_config file.
I don't know why I had to do this but worked for me!

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf is enabled but I don't think it is not working, why?, the name of the file is  50-cloud-init.conf, not *.conf

@user1751609 asterisk(*) on linux shells is a wildcard. simply it is used to match every file that ends with '.conf', so 50-cloud-init.conf is included.
